# How can a php file wait others?

Tags: php, javascript

I do code verification image in PHP and i show it in another page by calling it.

```
<img src="getVerifyImage.php"/>
```

where getVerifyImage.php prepares the image.

I also want to control the code in client side by using java script.

I create a session object which stores the code then i print it inside a hidden field. i read the code by using javascript.

however, the called php complete its run before the image prepared. as a result no session is created. when i try to create my hidden field.

How can i wait my page until getVerifyImage.php's execution is completed ?

Note : i can not use ajax, because ajax does not work on my server.i do not know why,but it is. i tested several times with other servers. my ajax codes did not work on this server.

Comment: Synchronous `xmlhttprequest` perhaps? I don't know how it would be implemented.

Comment: You can't, because `getVerifyImage.php` will be called only when your current PHP script has run. You will need to reload the page, or use Ajax to be able to access the verification result in PHP

Comment: putting the code in a hidden field defeats the purpose of image verification

Comment: @miki i know, but i really need this. my server administrator closed ajax ports and i need some client side verification for other input areas as long as for verification.

Comment: @Pekka when i reload the page, the image also refreshed.

Comment: Doesn't ajax use regular HTTP ports? Never used ajax with a different port than regular web resources use...

Comment: If your ajax requests are blocked, then so are your webpage requests.

Comment: i am not sure which ports ajax use. but i am sure ajax does not work with my server. i am not much concerned about server issue. the all my know ajax does not work.

Comment: then you're implementing your XmlHttpRequest object wrong.

Comment: @rlemon i tried my codes in several servers. i test several times. ajax really does not work.

Comment: Please read up on ***what*** XmlHttpRequest is and you'll understand why your question is invalid.

Comment: AJAX is the same as basic request on your PHP file. Actually, **it is** the same.

Comment: if you cannot make a XmlHttpReqest your regular http requests would also not work. ergo, if you can see a page you can use XmlHttpRequest object to pull the data.

Comment: @rlemon i know how to use XmlHttpRequest. my question is not about it. it was long time ago. i give in the ajax idea. my site do not use ajax any more.

Comment: you're implementing the *assuming Captcha* wrong if you are attempting to store the data on the page with the image. Please point me to your site and I'll show you how easy that system is to overcome. If you post your image generation code we can show you how to properly create the session variables so the user can be verified via a post or get request.

Comment: and I stand by my reasoning that if you ***claim*** that ajax does not run on your server due to closed ports, you have no bloody idea what XMLHttpRequest object is or what Ajax is (past being a buzzword and some funky jQuery magic)

Comment: session is created properly. however the calling pages complates its execution before the getVerifyImage.php. i can see the page is completed and image comes later. i also debug the pages. i see previous codes if is there any. it means that the getVerifyImage.php is completed after calling page. i will try to save image as a file and display on the page within a single php file. i think it works.

Comment: post some code otherwise how can we help. period.

Comment: @rlemon i really do not know why ajax doen not work. but it is so. i go crazy about it. i try the most basic ajax request. it did not work. however, they works properly on other servers.

Comment: create a new question for the xhr stuff, post your host, your 'attempted' xhr code, and I can guarantee you a solution - however with no information other than "it doesn't work, trust me" no a whole lot of help can be given. ***100% if normal http requests work xhr WILL work. no ifs ands or buts about it!***

Comment: @rlemon thanks for your interest. maybe i was wrong. i did my best about ajax. as i said before i give in the idea using ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **could** do that by moving your image generation code to a function, saving the image to disk, and then outputting a regular url to the `<img>` tag, from the same PHP file that generates the rest of your markup.

**HOWEVER, you shouldn't have your verification code added to your markup**. Quoting miki's comment above:

> putting the code in a hidden field defeats the purpose of image verification

Comment: i know, it is not a good idea putting the code inside page. however i really need this. i can not use ajax because the ports are closed it communicates. saving the image does not guarantees my calling php file use the image also the code.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is, create the image from the same PHP file that generates the rest of your markup, and send the final page to the browser (including the hidden field with the session variable's value).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="display:none;">
```

```
$(document).load(function(){
$("body").show();
$("#preload").remove();
}));
```

Maybe it works.

Comment: i am sorry. i did not put the info in my question. however, i can not use ajax because my server administrator closed the ports ajax communicates. i know it is stupid.

Comment: Ajax just uses the same port as a regular request made from your browser. If the admin blocked something, it's not the port.

Comment: @bfavaretto i was wrong about port comments. possibly it did not worked for other reasons. i do not know why.